# asp pages ceased, how to indicate it in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have redesigned my old asp site, now it's entirely in php/mysql.

I don't want to redirect pages (to many and too much file name changes), I just would like to indicate that my old asp pages don't exist anymore.

How to do it?

If I still decide later to make a few 301 redirects, where do I write them? Above or below the "ceased asp pages" entry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First create a file called `aspHandler.html` in site root directory with your custom messages about missing `asp` pages. Then create this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.asp$ /aspHandler.html [L,NC]
```

Later on to handle specific `asp` pages with `301` use:

```
RewriteRule ^page1\.asp$ /newpage1.php [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page2\.asp$ /newpage2.php [L,NC,R=301]
```